# Proof of Schwarz lemma 5

Tags: maxima-minima

I dont understand the following proof of Schwarz lemma:
[Schwarz Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma)
In the last section it says, "Moreover, suppose that $|f(z)| = |z|$ for some non-zero $z$ in $D$, or $|f'(0)| = 1$. Then, $|g(z)| = 1$ at some point of $D$".
Why does $g(z)$ have a local maximum then?

Comment: There is a proof following it, what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does $g$ have a local maximum? We cannot even ask that question because $g$ is complex valued. Maximum Modulus Theorem says if $|g|$ attains its maximum at an interior point of the domain then $g$ is a constant.

It is already proved that $|g(z)|\leq 1$. So $|g(z)|=1$ for some $z$ implies that $|g|$ attains its maximum at that point. This implies that $g$ is a constant $c$ so $f(z)=cz$.

Comment: I wanted to make sure that that you fullfil all requirements to apply the   Maximum Modulus Theorem.  |g| =1 is a local maximum, because we proved $|g(z)| \leq 1$. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Sorry. I have another question. Why does  |c| have to be 1?

Comment: @Steven33 Just apply the hypothesis: either $|f(z)|=|z|$ (with $ z\neq 0$) or $|f'(0)|=1$. In either case you get $|c|=1$.

Comment: It is $ g(z)=c$ Then we get  $ f'(0) =c $  and$ f(z)=cz. $. When you compare this expressions c must be 1?

Answer (score 0):

On that page, $D$ is defined to be the open complex unit disc: $D=\{z\in {\mathbb C}: |z|<1\}$ and $g$ is defined as
$$\left\{ g = \begin{eqnarray} \frac{f(z)}{z} \quad \mbox{ if } f(z) \not= 0  \\ f'(0) \quad \mbox{ otherwise }  \end{eqnarray} \right. $$

So by definition, either $|g(z)| = |f(z)/z| = |f(z)|/|z| = 1$ (since $|f(z)| = |z|$) or $|g(z)| = |f'(0)| = 1$.

Note that this isn't a local maximum really -- by the *maximum modulus principle* $g$ is now constant on $D$.